# How to do Trim operation to remove space character in a text field in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to do Trim operation to remove space character in a text field in JavaScript?

Comment: Google search for "Javascript trim" gives me 330,000 results in 0.16 seconds. Was that too long a wait for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you *did* mean Trim:

`x.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'');`

Answer (score 2):

A total dupe of this question:

[What is the best way to trim() in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196925/what-is-the-best-way-to-trim-in-javascript)

Unless you didn't actually mean trim of course and in fact wanted all the spaces replaced ? In which case you just want:

```
var myString = "foo bar ddd";
myString = myString.replace(/ /g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in FF and Chrome

```
var myString = "                  some text                  ";

alert(myString.trim());
```

In IE first use this and call like the example above.

```
// Adding trim function to String object
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  }
}
```

from here http://goo.gl/L802W