# 'trim()' javascript function issues with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, trim

`trim()` is not working in `Internet Explorer`(it's working properly in `Chrome` and `Firefox`). However I need to trim the value to prevent empty spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this turns out to be an IE bug, you can always implement your own workaround using RegEx in JavaScript like this [left trim function sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593859/left-trim-in-javascript/1593870#1593870) - the sample can be expanded to trim both left and right sides.  This Regex should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think JavaScript provides trim() does it? Some browsers may implement it, and various libraries implement it.

You can add your own, something like this:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look @ this -> [Trim not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: This one is easier by using **JQuery.trim(string);** and this solution is suitable for my application. **Because i am using JQuery** in my application.