# Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'trimLeft'

Tags: javascript

Not sure why I got this error :

> Object doesn't support property or method 'trimLeft' when browse with IE

My code is :

```
var checkTrimLeadingWhiteSpace = function(str) {
    if (str && ignoreLeadingWS) {
        return str.trimLeft();
    }

    return str;
};
```

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/TrimLeft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/TrimLeft) suggests the `trimLeft` function is non standard and should be avoided without a fallback.

However, you can write this:

```
var checkTrimLeadingWhiteSpace = function(str) {
   if (str && ignoreLeadingWS) {
     return str.replace(/^\s+/, "");
   }
   return str;
};
```

`replace(/^\s+/, "")` will remove all whitespaces in the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

> **trimLeft() :** (*Non-standard*)
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

The IE **Not support** `trimLeft()` method also you shouldn't use the *non-standard* functionnalities as the official documentation says.

You may search for **[Left Trim in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593859/left-trim-in-javascript)**.

Hope this helps.

**[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/TrimLeft)**.