# Javascript Switch statement not working as expected with string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the following switch statement in an ajax success callback:

```
success: function(datain) {
                    switch (datain)
                    {
                        case "ERROR. No ID. Try again":
                            $(".errors").append('There was an error.');
                            break;

                        case "ERROR. Wrong captcha. Try again":
                            $(".errors").append('There was an error.');
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

datain is a string (`typeof datain` returns `string`) and it does indeed contain the same text, capitalization and punctuation as the case so why would it not match either of the cases?

`console.log(datain)` and `console.log("ERROR. No ID. Try again")` match exactly and both return a `typeof` of `string` so why does my case never get matched?

---

**Solution and cause**

The solution is offered by palswim below `$.trim(datain)`. The cause was visible in Firebug and it was the fact that the string had a newline at the end while my switch case did not... so I was getting "foo\n" and trying to match "foo". Given that js uses `===` in the switch this, naturally (now that I see it), is why it failed.

Comment: try `datain === testStr`, for an appropriate datatin/testStr, and see what the result is. That should get you somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [trimming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196925/what-is-the-best-way-to-trim-in-javascript) your strings.

In jQuery:

```
switch($.trim(datain))
{ //...
```

But trying to match strings that long is fraught with peril!

Comment: I know :(. I'm stuck receiving some data from a bit of java middleware and I have no access to the code (nor knowledge of java even if I did). I'll try trimming and see how it goes...

Answer (score 1):

No clue as to why neither are called based on what you say.  At the risk of suggesting the obvious though:  Put in a "default" statement at the end of the switch to make sure you're function is being called, and in the default statement do some if comparisons: datain === "ERROR:...".

One other thing that might be easy to miss is if (possibly) there should be a "." at the end of "...Try again."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have a default at the end, I just left it off for my example. It turned out there was a newline at the end of the string that was causing it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
success: function(datain) {
                switch (datain)
                {
                    case `"ERROR. No ID. Try again"`:
                        $(".errors").append('There was an error.');
                        break;

                    case `"ERROR. Wrong captcha. Try again"`:
                        $(".errors").append('There was an error.');
                        break;
                }
            }
```

A character before " is `. It is right before 1 on my keyboard.