# How to trim document.getElementbyId value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to trim() in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196925/what-is-the-best-way-to-trim-in-javascript)

How to trim document.getElementbyId value in JavaScript?

Comment: this URL might help http://www.opensourcevarsity.com/javascriptbasics/l5trimmingwhitespaces

Comment: Without jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-to-trim-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: In your case, just take the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-to-trim-a-string-in-javascript/498995#498995) and have something like: `var value = document.getElementById("myInput").value; var trimmed = value.trim();`

Comment: Maybe you did not express it correctly, but trimming the value returned by `getElementbyId` does not make sense. It returns a DOM element.