# How to remove last and first spaces from a string?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I trim a string in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript)

I need to remove only the last and the first spaces from a generic string.

Example:

```
var str = " hello world "; // become "hello world"
var str = "ehi, do you come from ? "; // become "ehi, do you come from ?"
var str = "I am from Cina"; // remain "I am from Cina"
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196925/what-is-the-best-way-to-trim-in-javascript

Comment: That's called trimming. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript/8522376#8522376 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [trim from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) is what you are looking for.

`$.trim('  string with spaces at the ends   ');`

Or plain javascript:

`'  string with spaces at the ends   '.trim()`